# Calculate the radius of rectangle corner

Tags: geometry, circles, rectangles

TL;DR - rx = |x1-x0|; ry = |y1-y0|; is the formula for figuring out the radius of a rounded rectangle corner. It works with the first set of data but not the second. Why?

I need to calculate the radius of a corner of a rectangle and the data I have to figure it out with is some points along the curve. I am using Adobe Animate to make these rectangles and using code to get the data you see below.
Below is picture to illustrate what the data shows me:

[image: 3 points along corner]

I have learned that rx = |x1-x0|; ry = |y1-y0|;. So the topLeft radius is 321.4 - 301 and that gives me 20.4, which is pretty close to accurate (I told Animate to make the corner radii 20).

Here is the data I have to work with:

```
middleY: 321.4
middleX: 272.625
height: 40.8
width: 159.25

top: 301
bottom: 341.8
left: 193
right: 352.25
0: x: 331.85, y: 301
1: x: 346.25, y: 306.95
2: x: 352.25, y: 321.4
3: x: 352.25, y: 341.8
4: x: 213.4, y: 301
5: x: 193, y: 341.8
6: x: 193, y: 321.4
7: x: 198.95, y: 306.95
```

I have sorted it out to corners (top corners are curved and bottom are not):

```
    {
      "topLeft": [
        { "x": 213.4, "y": 301 },
        { "x": 193,"y": 321.4 },  -----> 321.4-301 = 20.4 OR 213.4-193 = 20.4
        { "x": 198.95,"y": 306.95 }
      ],
      "topRight": [
        { "x": 331.85,"y": 301 },
        { "x": 346.25,"y": 306.95 },     -----> 321.4-301 = 20.4 OR 352.25-331.85 = 20.4
        { "x": 352.25,"y": 321.4 }
      ],
      "bottomLeft": [
        { "x": 193,"y": 341.8 }
      ],
      "bottomRight": [
        { "x": 352.25,"y": 341.8 }
      ]
    }
```

When I make a rectangle with a **smaller width and height but still a radius of 20**, here is the data that I get:

```
top: 301.05
left: 199.55
height: 29
width: 144

middleY: 315.55 
middleX: 271.55
vertices: 
x: 343.55, y: 330.05,
x: 343.55, y: 314.9,
x: 338.1, y: 305.1,
x: 324.9, y: 301.05,
x: 205.05, y: 305.1,
x: 218.25, y: 301.05,
x: 199.55, y: 314.9,
x: 199.55, y: 330.05
"topLeft": [
  { "x": 205.05, "y": 305.1 },
  { "x": 218.25, "y": 301.05 },  ----->  314.05-301.05 = 13 OR 218.25-199.55 = 18.7
  { "x": 199.55, "y": 314.9 }
],
"topRight": [
  { "x": 343.55, "y": 314.9 },
  { "x": 338.1, "y": 305.1 },   ----->  314.05-301.05 = 13 OR 343.55-324.9 = 18.65
  { "x": 324.9, "y": 301.05 }
],
"bottomLeft": [
  { "x": 199.55, "y": 330.05 }
],
"bottomRight": [
  { "x": 343.55, "y": 330.05 }
]
```

Is it possible that Animate is giving me the wrong numbers or is there a way to calculate the radius to get 20 and I am just doing it wrong?

Or could there be some correlation between the width and height and the radius?

I found this site: https://planetcalc.com/8116/. It gives a radius of 20 for the first set of data ([here](https://planetcalc.com/8116/?x1=193&y1=321.4&x2=198.95&y2=306.95&x3=213.4&y3=301)) and a radius of 17 for the second set of data ([here](https://planetcalc.com/8116/?x1=199.55&y1=314.9&x2=205.05&y2=305.1&x3=218.25&y3=301.05)). I am leaning toward that the data is messed up.

Comment: Please consider clarifying definitions of all variables you use so that others don't need to guess.

Comment: It sounds like your math is fine but the thickness of the drawn line leaves room for error in your measurements. Also, how do you know from the image exactly where the curve ends and the straight line starts?

Comment: If you care to make your formula more accurate, you could use more points and then fit a circle through them.

Comment: @Karl Good question, it appears that is what is causing this issue. Could there be a correlation between the height and width and the radius of the corners?

Comment: @JosephCamacho I think that would be ideal, and I would do just that if Adobe Animate gave me more points. Unfortunately, all that the code gives me is the points I listed above.

Comment: I mean, if you tell your software to use a corner radius of 20px, I imagine it should do that and it shouldn't depend on the rectangle size. Whether that's what it actually does is a question for the developers (or the manual).

Comment: One reason may be that the setting of height: 29 is too small. It seemed that the software set 'the junction between curve and line' closer to the corner than the midpoint of the edge, that is why ry is smaller than rx. I assume that the software is doing something you are not expecting when the height is less than radius*2.